# how to rotate leaflet.js map

Tags: javascript, rotation, leaflet

I'm trying to rotate the map (or tileLayer) by x degrees. My research didn't produced any results that are not really dirty hacks and in my case doesn't work.

Is there a native leaflet.js way of rotating the map ?

(css rotate doesn't affect the mouse movement)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry to say, there is no way of natively rotating a Leaflet map. You'll need one of those ugly hacks or switch away from Leaflet and take a look at Mapbox GL JS or Open Layers 3:

- http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/navigation/
- http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/rotation.html

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes to new libraries... after some research open layers seems like the best choice for me

Comment: Do either of these providers charge?

Answer (score 3):

It works with leaflet-rotate-map https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-rotate-map

I use Turf.js to get bearing from current and prev point!

```
let bearing = turf.bearing(point1, point2);
mymap.setBearing(bearing*-1);
```

View [Screen-shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUsIo.png)

View [Complete animation](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AJFCJaUoJ1LWz-gSadn0aZAU6I_zCpkWhFmIzMan9RrBvJU3ohVTkmAqEUteVydsJ45h1MxCqIu1vFYY2XjAm4kHRIPVpCR_SOXhRxRyf8-JjhmqQ57altT_mq2o8QslYqEunD74VzbskFmslhe3z8MXGVhrSQ=w1080-h933-s-no?authuser=1)

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet does not support rotation, per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/268).

Comment: This issue was open 7 years ago. Anyone know if they ever added support?

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: I switched to openlayers and the ux was pretty bad with rotation so I switched back to leafletjs and will just skip rotation.

Comment: In addition to the options listed in the previous answer, the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) supports rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I hope this answer will still help someone since no one mentioned here this option so far:

https://github.com/Raruto/leaflet-rotate

It seems to be working pretty well, and it's recently updated. [Here's a demo.](https://raruto.github.io/leaflet-rotate/examples/leaflet-rotate.html)

As iH8 and many others mentioned, "there is no way of natively rotating a Leaflet map" and there might not be in the near/far future due to [this reason](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/268#issuecomment-1928759).
Meaning that rotating the map using this option will not update the map's labels - so in some scenarios, you might end up with your labels upside-down.