# Map angle rotation in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet

I need a plugin for leaflet to angle rotation in map.

I need to look at map rotation (degree) and then to build a new control with angle slider.

Is there any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060889/how-to-rotate-leaflet-js-map

Comment: I need a plugin for leaflet, how do i use mapbox tool in leaflet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map rotation is complicated. Some of us Leaflet devs have been working at it, but the complexity of making it work nicely means there are still a few issues with the current approaches. See, for example, https://github.com/fnicollet/Leaflet/issues.

We hope there will be a future Leaflet release with rotation support, but do not expect it in the near future.